# Where did you learn banking related concepts?

Tags: banking, terminology

I have only average knowledge of principle, interest, compound interest which I had learnt in high school.

Now-a-days, I am facing lot more new terms, like EMI, credit card, current account, service tax, fuel surcharge, mortage, premium and the list goes on. Neither I know these terms nor the banking processes. for example, Can I pay pay credit card bill in advance? Can I overpay? There is abstraction at our side. I want to open up that.

I found no place to learn all these. How had you learnt? Do you remember?

**[EDIT]**
I can learn the terms on Google but not the processes. For example, I thought I can pay credit card bill whenever I want. I made payment before the bill date which is not expected. This process is too general and uniform across all banks. The people will laugh at me for such foolish doubts, and they will take advantage(to sell any offer) if they come to know I am so dumb(This happened).

Comment: Google can also be helpful.

Comment: I think most of us learn these concepts one at a time, when we need them, rather than trying to explicitly study the financial industry.

Comment: Don't forget that context can matter. EMI could be the music company, Engineering Ministries International or Emergency Medical Insurance for a few possibilities. Similarly, taxes can vary from place to place so it could be worth noting what area are you looking for that information as some of us may assume your location is similar to ours which may not always be the case.

Comment: The Google is helpful only if I know exactly what I am looking for. Lets take example, bank person said you get 50 days interest free period for credit card. But in fact its only 20 days if I bought something on last day of billing cycle. This fact nobody told including Google. So I need more comprehensive resource than Google.

Comment: @Nilesh And that's exactly what you will find if you study the terms and conditions of your bank product. You won't find this information in a book.

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. Please take [the tour](http://money.stackexchange.com/tour) to see the kind of questions that are on topic here. As it stands, this question is far too broad. "The list goes on" means you have a dozen questions, if not more. Look at the top questions on this site, use tags and search to find the ones that will help you. Keep reading, keep learning.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a big chunk of your question is with regards to banking fees, and banks are usually rather transparent about those.

You should ask your bank, or any bank for that matter, for the prices for account servicing and credit cards, including marketing material that will describe the offered products. Then study those documents in detail, including the fine print.

After this, it should be absolutely clear to you when you will be charged and why.

If you have questions about a specific topic, an internet search will usually get you very far, and Wikipedia is a great resource too.

If, after reading and understanding the basics you still have questions, feel free to open a new topic here on StackExchange.

Comment: Studying bank documents is big challenge, it involves too many new words. They are too difficult to understand. I am asking about very basic concepts. I am in search of book/resource entitled __money guide for newbie__. I guess others learn these concepts by parents, friends.

Comment: How about to try it before to dismiss it so quickly? Sure, you can try and find some introductory books on banking, real estate, car loans etc. but this will still not cover the specifics of your own products. If you don't want to depend on bankers telling you how it is, you have to learn reading those documents. And frankly, it's really not that complicated. If there is a word or sentence you don't understand, look it up, or ask here. That's how most of us learned, and not through family and friends.